# Filter rows based on category IDs in a string

Tags: php

I have a lot of rows in a database that have categories linked to it. Although the categories are concatenated with a comma  as a string in one field.

For example;

```
name | categoryIDs
------------------
jack | 5,6,9,16
john | 6,8,9,16
mike | 2,5,7,10
brad | 3,5,7,16
```

I have a request and need to filter all the rows based on the request that has the categories in an array like this;

```
data = [
    'maths' => 6,
    'science' => 16
]
```

So in this case all the rows that has 6 **and** 16 in the categoryIDs field need to be returned.

I thought of using array_filter, but I still struggle too much with callback functions or anonymized functions inside the method.

I tried this but I don't get it;

```
$data = [
    'maths' => 6,
    'science' => 16,
];

$rows = $this->getRecords();

$result = array_filter($rows, function ($row) use ($data) {
    if (in_array($data, explode(',', $row['categoryIDs']))) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

I don't get any results back, the array remains empty. Can somebody please explain and show how I can do this the best way? Any other options are welcome too. Unfortunately I'm stuck with the categoryIDs provided as a string per row. It won't be possible to retrieve them any other way. But if I can manipulate that field first before filtering, it could work as well. Any ideas?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: in_array compares your needle with each element in array. Here data is an associative array and the element is a number. you cannot compare them. instead, loop through each of the values of $data and do in array with each value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

Actually, you are trying to find an array inside another array.
But, the code `in_array([6,16], [1,6,8])` can't return `true`.

### A solution

You can use [`array_intersect()`](https://www.php.net/array_intersect) to compare exploded values and `$data` values.

### The code

```
<?php
$data = [
    'maths' => 6,
    'science' => 16,
];

// $rows = $this->getRecords();
// changed to static data for the test
$rows = [
    ['name' => 'jack', 'categoryIDs' => '5,6,9,16'],
    ['name' => 'john', 'categoryIDs' => '6,8,9,16'],
    ['name' => 'mike', 'categoryIDs' => '2,5,7,10'],
    ['name' => 'brad', 'categoryIDs' => '3,5,7,16'],
    ];

$result = array_filter($rows, function ($row) use ($data) {
    $ids = explode(',', $row['categoryIDs']);
    return count(array_intersect($data, $ids)) == count($data);
});

print_r($result);
```

### Output

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [name] => jack
            [categoryIDs] => 5,6,9,16
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [name] => john
            [categoryIDs] => 6,8,9,16
        )
)
```

### Note

For performance, instead of counting `$data` each time, you could count it and pass to the anonymous function this value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks good, but not quite there yet. I don't want brad to be returned. I only want the records where all categories exist, not just a few of them like only 16 in brad's case. Only jack and john has 6 AND 16. So only those two should be returned

Comment: @Mentos93 You're welcome. OK, I've edited my answer to get only jack and john. See `count(array_intersect($data, $ids)) == count($data)`.